# Flutterfire configuration for Desktop app

Tags: linux, flutter, firebase, desktop, flutter-linux

I am trying to build a Desktop app with Flutter and Firebase . I am not able to find how to run the configuration. The flutterfire configuration have only options for iOS,Android and Web. Can we update the firebase_options.dart to include Linux and other desktop app.

I get below while running the Linux app.

Syncing files to device Linux...
flutter: Run Firebase.initializeApp
flutter: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
#0      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:181:7)
#1      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)

[result of flutterfire configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdh9T.png)

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte